# recover hacked magento checkout

Tags: html, xml, magento, server

I am trying to solve a problem for one of my clients webshops using magento v1.x, which was hacked a couple of days ago. They have removed all original payment options, and replaced it with their own credit card form. I have tried setting everything back trough the Magento webshop manager, but there all options are correct with the correct payment settings (we had a simular attack a long time ago, but then they simply changed the settings via the Magento Manager, so that was an easy fix back then).

I have tried recovering a backup of the webshop, loosing all items added after that (aprox 7k items, all with hand placed pictures, 3 per item), but even then only the credit card checkout remains on the website. After that I have tried copying the entire public_html folder from a working backup, direclty into the server, and again, only the credit card chechout remains.

Where can I start searching next if even replacing the entire public_html folder doesnt solve this problem? Can they be redirecting a part of the Magento code to their own?

All help is welcome!

Comment: Firstly, apply the Magento security patches!!!

Comment: and apply an IP block on to the Admin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: yes this is coding relateds since I have to change the code manually as Magento's manager doesnt work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

First of all apply all Magento security patches. After that, check `Payment options` page in `System >> Configuration`. There is probably some extra payment method added there. If not, you should check the checkout url is it the default one (there might be some redirect added from your old site to hackers site. If it is the correct url, inspect element for credit card part, to find a piece of code that you could search for in the codebase or in database.

After that you should search all tables in the database for that string (that you inspected) - you can do that using search functionality in PhpMyAdmin easily.

After that search through the whole codebase for that string, to see where it is injected.

Hope that this will help you!

Comment: I wasnt able to do these patches due to it being a known issue with Magento v1. I will see if there is a work around for that tomorrow.

Currently all payment methods are disabled except for the two my clients wants. I have tried finding redirections by inspecting the elements on his website, but nothing seems to be off except for the CC fields, and neither can I find any unknown links. This is why I hoped that I could get a hint on folder structure level instead, because even replacing the entire public_html folder didnt solve the checkout problem, while the site changed in other places.

Comment: @sdieters did you also try with old database?

Comment: yes. A backup of the old database didnt work, and neither did replacing the hacked public_html with the public_html backup of a working website.